# Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm able to get the difference between two dates using MomentJs as follows:

```
moment(end.diff(startTime)).format("m[m] s[s]")
```

However, I also want to display the hour when applicable (only when >= 60 minutes have passed).

However, when I try to retrieve the duration hours using the following:

```
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.hours();
```

it is returning the current hour and not the number of hours between the two dates.

How do I get the difference in hours between two Moments?

Answer (score 834, accepted):

You were close. You just need to use the `duration.asHours()` method (see [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/)).

```
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.asHours();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `startTime.diff(end, 'hours', true);`? The duration.asHours(); would return 1 if it was 25 hours ago.

Comment: @DanielF If you are using MomentJS >= version 2.0.0, you could use `.diff()`, yes. Except it would be `end.diff(startTime, 'hours', true)` to get the number of hours as a positive number. However, your second point is not correct. `duration.hours()` would return 1 if it was 25 hours ago, but `duration.asHours()` would return 25.

Comment: @GregL I stand corrected https://jsfiddle.net/qxxr1Lyr/ I must have mistakenly used the `.hours()` method without noticing.

Comment: @zanderwar I understand your frustration, but this is a 5 year old question. Today such questions & answers wouldn't fly.

Comment: `05/12/2019 11:00 PM` and `06/12/2019 12:00 AM`  is returning me 8761 while it should be 1 hour only

Comment: @alamnaryab This is likely because you are not using a standard format for dates, so it is trying to interpret the dates in the current locale, which might be one of the crazy ones, like America, which is `MM/DD/YYYY`. I suggest you create your moment instances by specifying the format, using sth like: `var start = moment('05/12/2019 11:00 PM', 'DD/M/YYYY h:mm A');`. Then the code I posted will work as expected.

Comment: yes, I fixed it by changing format before diff, thank you

Comment: Property 'diff' does not exist on type 'Date'

Comment: @integrater Is `end` in your code a Moment instance? Try wrapping it with `moment()` to convert it. `.diff()` is a MomentJS method only available on Moment objects, not native JS Date objects.

Comment: In my case i wanted duration in milliseconds. so i used `var mSec = duration.asMilliseconds();` thanks

Answer (score 327):

Following code block shows how to calculate the difference in number of days between two dates using MomentJS.

```
var now = moment(new Date()); //todays date
var end = moment("2015-12-1"); // another date
var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(end));
var days = duration.asDays();
console.log(days)
```

Comment: This answer is clear enough and even more complete for me than the accepted answer above, where you do not know where 'end' and 'startTime' come from... Thanks a lot for your answer Raj!

Comment: It's a little simpler to get now by `var now = moment();`. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/

Comment: Hi, you can also use the moment.duration.days() in order to get the days (0 - 30).

Here is the doc: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/

Answer (score 223):

Or you can do simply:

```
var a = moment('2016-06-06T21:03:55');//now
var b = moment('2016-05-06T20:03:55');

console.log(a.diff(b, 'minutes')) // 44700
console.log(a.diff(b, 'hours')) // 745
console.log(a.diff(b, 'days')) // 31
console.log(a.diff(b, 'weeks')) // 4
```

docs: [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Comment: How can I show all hours, minutes and seconds together? Like HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: @FaizanSaiyed, I know it's late but, here's how to do -
`var a = moment('2016-06-06T22:34:56');
var b = moment('2016-06-06T21:03:55');
var diff_s = a.diff(b, 'seconds');
console.log(moment.utc(moment.duration(diff_s, "seconds").asMilliseconds()).format("hh:mm:ss"))`

Answer (score 48):

There is a great `moment` method called `fromNow()` that will return the time from a specific time in nice human readable form, like this:

```
moment('2019-04-30T07:30:53.000Z').fromNow() // an hour ago || a day ago || 10 days ago
```

Or if you want that between two specific dates you can use:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
a.from(b); // "a day ago"
```

Taken from the Docs:

- [`fromNow()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)
- [`from()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/)

Comment: This is the best approach for me, as I don't need to calculate the hours/days/months/years-ago-strings myself and it is just one line! Thank you!!

Comment: You can also pass a boolean to `from`/`fromNow` to remove the prefix from it. By default, it will return like `in 5 minutes`. Using the boolean (`a.from(b, true)`) you get only `5 minutes`.

Answer (score 29):

All you need to do is pass in `hours` as the second parameter to moments diff function.

```
var a = moment([21,30,00], "HH:mm:ss")
var b = moment([09,30,00], "HH:mm:ss")
a.diff(b, 'hours') // 12
```

**Docs:** https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

**Example:**

```js
const dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
// Get your start and end date/times
const rightNow = moment().format(dateFormat);
const thisTimeYesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format(dateFormat);
// pass in hours as the second parameter to the diff function
const differenceInHours = moment(rightNow).diff(thisTimeYesterday, 'hours');

console.log(`${differenceInHours} hours have passed since this time yesterday`);
```

```html
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 24):

I know this is old, but here is a one liner solution:

```
const hourDiff = start.diff(end, "hours");
```

Where **start** and **end** are moment objects.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 13):

You just need to use the date.diff() method in moment.js

```js
const now = moment.utc();
var end = moment("2021-09-13"); 
var days = now.diff(end, "days"); 
console.log(days)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I wanted hours and minutes:

```
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.hours(); //hours instead of asHours
var minutes = duration.minutes(); //minutes instead of asMinutes
```

For more info refer to the official [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/).

Answer (score 3):

```
var __startTime = moment("2016-06-06T09:00").format();
var __endTime = moment("2016-06-06T21:00").format();

var __duration = moment.duration(moment(__endTime).diff(__startTime));
var __hours = __duration.asHours();
console.log(__hours);
```

Comment: Remove all the unneeded conversions from/to string representations of moments and you will end up with the accepted answer.

Comment: Why the extra underscores at the start of variable names?

Answer (score 3):

Source: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```js
let startDate = "2022-08-14";

let endDate = "2022-08-20";

let startDateMoment = moment(startDate.split('-')); // ["2022", "08", "14"]

let endDateMoment = moment(endDate.split('-'));

console.log('Difference: ', endDateMoment.diff(startDateMoment, 'hours')); // 6
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var start=moment(1541243900000);
 var end=moment(1541243942882);
 var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(startTime));
 var hours = duration.asHours();
```

As you can see, the start and end date needed to be moment objects for this method to work.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered but in case you want something recursive and more generic and not relying on moment `fromNow` you could use this function I created. Of course you can change its logic to adjust it to your needs to also support years and seconds.

```
var createdAt = moment('2019-05-13T14:23:00.607Z');
var expiresAt = moment('2019-05-14T14:23:00.563Z');

// You can also add years in the beginning of the array or seconds in its end
const UNITS = ["months", "weeks", "days", "hours", "minutes"]
function getValidFor (createdAt, expiresAt, unit = 'months') {
    const validForUnit = expiresAt.diff(createdAt, unit);
    // you could adjust the if to your needs 
    if (validForUnit > 1 || unit === "minutes") {
    return [validForUnit, unit];
  }
  return getValidFor(createdAt, expiresAt, UNITS[UNITS.indexOf(unit) + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**As per the new Deprecation warning of Moment JS[image]**

You need to pass Format of Start and end date Format along with values for example :

```
   let trackStartTime = "2020-12-29 09:59:19.07 +05:30";
   let trackEndTime = "2020-12-29 11:04:19.07 +05:30" || moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS Z");
   let overallActivity = moment.duration(moment(trackEndTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS Z').diff(moment(trackStartTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS Z'))).asHours();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want total minutes between two dates in day wise than may below code will help full to you **Start Date : 2018-05-04 02:08:05** , **End Date : 2018-05-14 09:04:07**...

```
function countDaysAndTimes(startDate,endDate){
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
var dayObj = new Object;
var finalArray = new Array;

var datetime1 = moment(startDate);
var datetime2 = moment(endDate);
if(datetime1.format('D') != datetime2.format('D') || datetime1.format('M') != datetime2.format('M') ||  datetime1.format('YYYY') != datetime2.format('YYYY')){
  var onlyDate1 = startDate.split(" ");
  var onlyDate2 = endDate.split(" ");
  var totalDays = moment(onlyDate2[0]).diff(moment(onlyDate1[0]), 'days')

  // First Day Entry
  dayObj.startDate = startDate;
  dayObj.endDate = moment(onlyDate1[0]).add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD')+" 00:00:00";
  dayObj.minutes = moment(dayObj.endDate).diff(moment(dayObj.startDate), 'minutes');
  finalArray.push(dayObj);

  // Between Days Entry
  var i = 1;
  if(totalDays > 1){
    for(i=1; i<totalDays; i++){
      var dayObj1 = new Object;
      dayObj1.startDate = moment(onlyDate1[0]).add(i, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD')+" 00:00:00";
      dayObj1.endDate = moment(onlyDate1[0]).add(i+1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD')+" 00:00:00";
      dayObj1.minutes = moment(dayObj1.endDate).diff(moment(dayObj1.startDate), 'minutes');
      finalArray.push(dayObj1);
    }
  }

  // Last Day Entry
  var dayObj2 = new Object;
  dayObj2.startDate = moment(onlyDate1[0]).add(i, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD')+" 00:00:00";
  dayObj2.endDate = endDate ;
  dayObj2.minutes = moment(dayObj2.endDate).diff(moment(dayObj2.startDate), 'minutes');
  finalArray.push(dayObj2);

}
else{
  dayObj.startDate = startDate;
  dayObj.endDate = endDate;
  dayObj.minutes = datetime2.diff(datetime1, 'minutes');
  finalArray.push(dayObj);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArray));
// console.table(finalArray);
resolve(finalArray);
});
}
```

> Output

```
 [
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-04 02:08:05",
  "endDate":"2018-05-05 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1311
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-05 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-06 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-06 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-07 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-07 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-08 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-08 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-09 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-09 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-10 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-10 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-11 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-11 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-12 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-12 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-13 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-13 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-14 00:00:00",
  "minutes":1440
  },
  {
  "startDate":"2018-05-14 00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2018-05-14 09:04:07",
  "minutes":544
  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to pass moment date simple**

```
const getTimeDuration = (_startTime: string, _endTime: any) => {
  if (!_startTime || !_endTime) return `${0} hr ${0} min`;
  let duration: moment.Duration = moment.duration(
    moment(_endTime, 'HH:mm A').diff(moment(_startTime, 'HH:mm A')),
  );
  let hours = duration.asHours();
  let minutes = duration.asMinutes() % 60;
  return `${hours} hr ${minutes} min`;
};

getTimeDuration("2023-10-25T14:41:21.633Z","2023-10-25T16:41:00.000Z")
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe could usefull for someone

```
          var ax = moment(
            new Date().toLocaleString(), // today/now is 09/12/2021 10:00:00
            "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
            ).diff(
              moment(
                "12/11/2022 13:43:11", // some time in future or past
                "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
              )
          );
          console.log('if today is in the future of the compared date then 
          result should be negative ==>', ax);
          // ax bigger than 0 zero means date in past. ms less than zero is in future
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 calcDifferential(from, to) {
      const fromTime = this.$moment(from, 'hh:mm:ss')
      const toTime = this.$moment(to, 'hh:mm:ss')
      const ms = toTime.diff(fromTime)
      const d = this.$moment.duration(ms)
      const s = d.format()
      return s
    }
```

Answer (score -14):

```
            var timecompare = {
            tstr: "",
            get: function (current_time, startTime, endTime) {
                this.tstr = "";
                var s = current_time.split(":"), t1 = tm1.split(":"), t2 = tm2.split(":"), t1s = Number(t1[0]), t1d = Number(t1[1]), t2s = Number(t2[0]), t2d = Number(t2[1]);

                if (t1s < t2s) {
                    this.t(t1s, t2s);
                }

                if (t1s > t2s) {
                    this.t(t1s, 23);
                    this.t(0, t2s);
                }

                var saat_dk = Number(s[1]);

                if (s[0] == tm1.substring(0, 2) && saat_dk >= t1d)
                    return true;
                if (s[0] == tm2.substring(0, 2) && saat_dk <= t2d)
                    return true;
                if (this.tstr.indexOf(s[0]) != 1 && this.tstr.indexOf(s[0]) != -1 && !(this.tstr.indexOf(s[0]) == this.tstr.length - 2))
                    return true;

                return false;

            },
            t: function (ii, brk) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
                    if (i < ii)
                        continue;
                    var s = (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i + "";
                    this.tstr += "," + s;
                    if (brk == i)
                        break;
                }
            }};
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation rather than just posting code?