# Hour difference between two times(HH:MM:SS a)in momentjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs

I have two time without date

```
var startTime="12:16:59 am";
var endTime="06:12:07 pm";
```

I want to show the total hours in between the above times by using `moment.js.`

If it's not possible in  `moment.js` then please let me know using by `javascript`.

**Inputs:**

```
var startTime="01:30:00 am";
var endTime="2:45:07 pm";
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1 hour and 15 minutes
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Comment: @ShaunakD duplicate is not accetable cause will return asTOTAL values

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Get Hours

I got the hours by using this code

```
endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours')
```

### Get Minutes

i got the minutes by using this below code

```
var mins = moment.utc(moment(endTime, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(startTime, "HH:mm:ss"))).format("mm")
```

### My Working code is

```
$scope.UpdateTimeSheet = function (rowEntity) {   
  if (rowEntity.StartTime.toString().length != 11) {
    rowEntity.StartTime = moment(rowEntity.StartTime).format("hh:mm:ss a");
  }

  if (rowEntity.EndTime.toString().length != 11) {
    rowEntity.EndTime = moment(rowEntity.EndTime).format("hh:mm:ss a");
  }

  var startTime = moment(rowEntity.StartTime, "hh:mm:ss a");
  var endTime = moment(rowEntity.EndTime, "hh:mm:ss a");

  var mins = moment.utc(moment(endTime, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(startTime, "HH:mm:ss"))).format("mm")

  rowEntity.TotalHours = endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours') + " Hrs and " + mins + " Mns";

}
```

Answer (score 79):

Try code below

```js
// start time and end time
var startTime = moment('12:16:59 am', 'HH:mm:ss a');
var endTime = moment('06:12:07 pm', 'HH:mm:ss a');

// calculate total duration
var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));

// duration in hours
var hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());

// duration in minutes
var minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes()) % 60;

alert(hours + ' hour and ' + minutes + ' minutes.');
```

Check fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/gs69Lv5x/

Comment: var startTime=moment("09:00:00 pm", "HH:mm:ss a");
var endTime=moment("04:00:00 am", "HH:mm:ss a");
var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());
var minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes())%60;
alert (hours + ' hour and '+ minutes+' minutes.');
Ouput is -17 hours. But it should have been 7 hours.
Can you please tell me if i am doing something wrong

Comment: yes I saw that, it's happening when we put pm before am. Mostly people do calculate only when it's day changed. I have found solution but it's not a robust. Once I have robust solution probably by today, then I will update my answer.

Answer (score 15):

```
var startTime = moment("12:16:59 am", 'hh:mm:ss a');
var endTime = moment("06:12:07 pm", 'hh:mm:ss a');

endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours');
```

Comment: It's return hour only, not minutes :( .

Comment: @RameshRajendran You asked total hours in the question. So, what's your exact expectation ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I don't think moment has inbuilt support for this

Comment: @RameshRajendran Check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript

Answer (score 10):

```
//Get start time and end time
var startTime = moment("12:16:59 am", "HH:mm:ss a"),
endTime = moment("06:12:07 pm", "HH:mm:ss a");
```

1. Method 1

---

```
var dif = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
console.log([dif.hours(), dif.minutes(), dif.seconds()].join(':'));
console.log('dif in Mins: ', (dif.hours() * 60) + dif.minutes());
```

2. Method 2

---

```
console.log('hrs: ', moment(endTime).diff(startTime, 'hours'));
console.log('dif in Mins: ', moment(endTime).diff(moment(startTime), 'minutes'));
```

3. Method 3

---

```
var hrs = moment.utc(endTime.diff(startTime)).format("HH");
var min = moment.utc(endTime.diff(startTime)).format("mm");
var sec = moment.utc(endTime.diff(startTime)).format("ss");
console.log([hrs, min, sec].join(':'));
```

4. Formatted output

---

```
var dif = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
console.log(dif.humanize());
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
myStart = "01:30:00 am";
myEnd = "2:45:07 am";

function getTimeDiff(start, end) {

  return moment.duration(moment(end, "HH:mm:ss a").diff(moment(start, "HH:mm:ss a")));
}

diff = getTimeDiff(myStart, myEnd)
console.log(`${diff.hours()} Hour ${diff.minutes()} minutes`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me; the best solution so far

```
function calculateTimeDifference() {
    var date1 = new Date();
    var date2 = new Date();

    var diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    var msec = diff;
    var hh = `0${Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60)}`;
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;

    var mm = `0${Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60)}`;
    msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;

    var ss = `0${Math.floor(msec / 1000)}`;
    msec -= ss * 1000;

    return hh.slice(-2) + ":" + mm.slice(-2) + ":" + ss.slice(-2); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var startTime = moment("12:16:59 am", 'hh:mm:ss a');
var endTime = moment("06:12:07 pm", 'hh:mm:ss a');

var totalHours = (endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours'));
var totalMinutes = endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes');
var clearMinutes = totalMinutes % 60;
console.log(totalHours + " hours and " + clearMinutes + " minutes");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var start = moment.duration("09:45", "HH:mm");
var end = moment.duration("10:30", "HH:mm");
var diff = end.subtract(start);
diff.hours(); // return hours
diff.minutes(); // return minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is marked as already answered but you can literally just do...

```
moment.utc(moment.duration(moment(dateA).diff(moment(dateB))).asMilliseconds()).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: That's really ugly code... is there anything your code does better than the other?

Comment: The question was how can you do this in momentjs, this is how and its in one line.

Comment: This is the only answer that allows easily changing the format (e.g. HH:mm:ss to mm:ss)

Answer (score 1):

```
 const end = moment(event.end, "HH:mm:ss")
 const start = moment(event.start, "HH:mm:ss")
 const dif = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
 const formattedDiff = dif.minutes() > 0 ? `${(dif.hours() + dif.minutes() / 60)} hrs` : `${dif.hours()} hrs`
// Result: 1.5 hrs / 2 hrs / 4.25 hrs
```

I came up with this solution to show up `difference` in hour(s) (minutes converted, you can use Math.floor for minutes maybe but my case the minutes are always half/quarter)

Answer (score 0):

I got it from `@Vigneswaran Marimuthu`

```
var startTime = moment("12:16:59 am", 'hh:mm:ss a');
var endTime = moment("06:12:07 pm", 'hh:mm:ss a');

var result = endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours') + " Hrs and " +     
            endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes') + " Mns";
```

> If we want to get seconds, then you  just rewrite the code `"seconds"` instead of `hours`

Answer (score 0):

For - "12:00:01" Format without am, pm format following os the code..

```
   var startTime = moment('12:00:01', 'hh:mm:ss a');
   var endTime = moment('13:00:10' , 'hh:mm:ss a');
   var totalHours = (endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours'));
   var totalMinutes = endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes');
   var clearMinutes = totalMinutes % 60;
   alert(totalHours + " hours and " + clearMinutes + " minutes");
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var fromtime = moment($('#fromtime').val(), "HH:mm");
var totime = moment($('#totime').val(), "HH:mm");
var dif = moment.duration(totime.diff(fromtime));
var diff = [dif.hours(), dif.minutes()].join(':');
if(diff != "NaN:NaN" && dif.hours()>=0 && dif.minutes()>=0){
    $('#duration').text([dif.hours(), dif.minutes()].join(':'));
}else{
    $('#duration').text('');
}
```

Comment: Any explanation would help viewer a lot.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work. Maybe just use code *fences* rather than pretend it's a runnable snippet?

Answer (score -2):

```
var startTime = moment("12:16:59");
var endTime = moment("06:12:07");

var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.asHours();
```

Comment: Moment constructor like this is discouraged and will be removed in future. Try to use with format :)