# calculate difference between two times in moment js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I'm writing a service in node js. I have used moment js for time related solutions.
I want to calculate the time difference between two times. Here is my snippet and it's not giving me the desired output :

```js
var now = moment('11:08:30',"H:mm:ss");
var prev = moment('11:07:30', "H:mm:ss");
var result = moment(now.diff(prev)).format("H:mm:ss");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

As per my understanding, I think the difference between `11:08:30` and `11:07:30` should come out as 00:01:00 but instead the output is coming as `5:31:00`. I don't understand why this is happening. How do I fix it so that the output is `00:01:00` i.e 1 minute ?

Comment: `now.diff(prev)` returns the difference in milliseconds, in your case `60000`. With `moment(60000)` you create a date `60000` milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC. If you now call `.format("H:mm:ss")` then `H` would be influenced by the timezone of your system. So you need to ensure that you work with utc while formatting.

Comment: So just change `moment(now.diff(prev)).format("H:mm:ss")` to `moment.utc(now.diff(prev)).format("H:mm:ss")`as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29747198/1960455) and you have the output `0:01:00`

Comment: hey thank you soo much this really solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example,

```js
var now = moment('11:08:30',"H:mm:ss");
var prev = moment('11:07:30', "H:mm:ss");

 function dateDifference(startDate, endDate){
        return moment(startDate).diff(moment(endDate), 'seconds');
    }
    console.log(this.dateDifference(now,prev))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> The supported measurements are years, months, weeks, days, hours,
>   minutes, and seconds. For ease of development, the singular forms are
>   supported as of 2.0.0. Units of measurement other than milliseconds
>   are available in version 1.1.1.

---

Now, once u get answer in seconds, then please follow this link to convert seconds into your desired format 'h:mm:ss'

[format seconds into 'hh:mm:ss'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss)

Comment: it's throwing error in the console

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Comment: If you post a snippet then check if it really runs. And the question is about javascript and not TypeScript.

Comment: Updated the code please check again. working fine, let me know if u have any doubs

Comment: The OP is asking how to correct the code so that it is `00:01:00` and not `01:01:00`, your code outputs `1`.

Comment: @t.niese  I'll make sure that in future posted sinepets work perfectly.

Comment: yes please how to output it as H:mm:ss would be really helpful

Comment: @t.niese current version of moment.js does not support that particular format please check out my full answer.

Comment: @pravinnavle to display in that format what you can do is,

calculate the difference in 'seconds' format and then convert it into 'hh:mm:ss'.
I hope this was helpful

Comment: @siddharthshah That's what the OP is doing right now. `now.diff(prev)` returns `60000` and then the OP does `.format("H:mm:ss")` which results in `1:01:00` instead of the expected `0:01:00`.

Comment: @pravinnavle if you still have any confusion then let me know, I'll add that calculation for format into the snippet also.
Thanks.

Comment: @t.niese
then he has to calculate the difference in 'seconds' format and then convert it into 'hh:mm:ss'.

Comment: @pravinnavle I've updated the answer please check.