# Convert string to Timestamp in Javascript using MomentJS

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs, timestampdiff

I have a string like :

```
var from = '2016-06-06T21:03:55' ;
```

Now how do I convert it into a timestamp such that I can give it as an input to momentjs. 
Basically, I want to find the difference in the timestamps as seen in this post : [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js/37092950#37092950)

Look at the last answer in the above post.

Please please help em out. I am stck on it since hours now.

Comment: It's a valid date, so just `new Date(from)` would get you a date object, and the difference would be just `date1.getHours()  - date2.getHours()` without an entire library to do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass this variable to the moment ctor.

```
var from = '2016-06-06T21:03:55' ;
var a = moment('2016-06-06T22:03:55');
var b = moment(from);

console.log(a.diff(b, 'minutes')); //60
console.log(a.diff(b, 'hours')); //1
console.log(a.diff(b, 'days')); //0 
console.log(a.diff(b, 'weeks')); //0
```

Or you can use the format method to see the value fo the moment variables, like :

```
b.format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss'); // 06/06/2016 09:03:55
b.format(); // 2016-06-06T21:03:55+10:00
```

Comment: Ash , if I pass from variable to moment as paramtere , the value of b is : 716400000
That's so wierd

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1

You can initialize a Date object and call getTime() to get it in Unix form. It comes out in milliseconds so you'll need to divide by 1000 to get it in seconds.

```
(new Date("2016/06/06 21:03:55").getTime()/1000)
```

It may have decimal bits so wrapping it in `Math.round` would clean that.

```
Math.round(new Date("2016/06/06 21:03:55").getTime()/1000)
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nanilab/0jpxu30z/

### Option 2

The `Date.parse()` method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC or NaN if the string is unrecognized or, in some cases, contains illegal date values (e.g. 2015-02-31).

```
var input = "2016-06-06 21:03:55";
input = input.split(" - ").map(function (date){
    return Date.parse(date+"-0500")/1000;
}).join(" - ");
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nanilab/cweq2q0q/

[image]

Comment: Option 2 should be avoided: "It is not recommended to use Date.parse"... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse