# How to get total minutes of difference between two dates using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

*Updated My Question*

**How to get total minutes of difference between two dates using pure JavaScript when**

Condition (1):: Same month, same year but date changes

```
newDate: 18/10/2016 0:50
oldDate: 17/10/2016 23:05
```

Condition (2):: Last date of current month and 1st date of next month

```
newDate: 1/11/2016 0:50  
oldDate: 31/10/2016 23:05
```

Condition (3):: Last date of year and 1st date of new year

```
newDate: 1/1/2017 0:50  
oldDate: 31/12/2016 23:05
```

*Note: Please have a look newDate and oldDate to understand the conditions.*

*Thanks*

Comment: consider using momentjs http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Parse the string and create `Date` objects from them, and compare those.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript l2 google.

Comment: this could also help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js

Comment: @Darkrum thanks for your help, going to delete this question soon

Comment: M sorry to add this question again

Comment: You can down vote the question how many times you want via comment too.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me the link to fulfill last 3 conditions without using any js library ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: I don't think the `question is unclear` anymore @RobG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to use a library for parsing date strings, you can write a simple function such as:

```js
// Parse date string in "Sat Dec 31 2016 15:35:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" format
function parseDate(s) {
  // Split into tokens
  var b = s.match(/\w+/g) || [];
  var months = 'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split(' ');
  // Determine offset in minutes
  var offSign = /GMT+/.test(s)? -1 : 1;
  var offset = b[8].substr(0,2)*60 + +b[8].substr(2,2);
  // Create date, applying offset to minutes
  var date = new Date(Date.UTC(b[3],
             months.indexOf(b[1].toLowerCase()), 
             b[2], 
             b[4],
             +b[5] + (offSign*offset),
             b[6]));
  return date;
}

var d = parseDate("Sat Dec 31 2016 15:35:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)")
console.log('UTC: ' + d.toISOString() + '\n' +
            'Local: ' + d.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Great !!! Now can you please explain how do i get total difference of time by dividing new date minus old date ?

Comment: You can get the difference between two dates in milliseconds simply by subtracting one from the other, e.g. for one day: `new Date(2016,0,2) - new Date(2016,0,1)`, there are [*many questions about that already*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+between+dates). ;-)

Comment: This is much better, I haven't tried your code in my project but I appreciate your answer and replies.

Answer (score 0):

Completed My Requirements with the below pure JavaScript code

In my code starttime and endtime are

```
//var startTime = localStorage.getItem("starttime");
//var endTime = new Date();
```

Example Here.

```
var startTime = new Date("Sat Dec 31 2016 15:35:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
var endTime = new Date("Sun Jan 1 2017 15:35:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");

var totalMiliseconds = endTime - startTime;
alert(totalMiliseconds);
//output:: 86400000

var totalSeconds = totalMiliseconds/1000;
alert(totalSeconds);
//output:: 86400

var totalMinuts = totalSeconds/60;
alert(totalMinuts);
//output:: 1440

var totalHours = totalMinuts/60;
alert(totalHours);
//output:: 24
```

And this fulfill my all 3 conditions.

*Thank You For Your Support !!!*

Comment: Do not parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing). Always use a parse function or library.

Comment: I have stored start time and date into localstorage so while reusing the same date I need to parse it with date constructor.

Comment: You do not **need** to use the Date constructor, it's a poor choice for parsing. Use a simple parse function or one of the many good parsing and formatting libraries like [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) or [*moment.js*](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: but as I have mentioned before that already I have added many js libraries like scrollbox.js touchswipe.js and other so do not wants to add one more. Thanks btw @RobG

Comment: If you don't want to use a library (fecha.js is just 2k), write a simple function to parse your particular format.