# How to get number of hours form date in string till now in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I seem to have more trouble than necessary.

I have a date in the past in string, say: `2017-01-09T10:23:13.000Z`

I want to get the number of hours till `now`.

What operations should I perform?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

use moment.duration and duration.asHours for this.

You can get the current datetime now using moment() and get the duration of now from the datetime you have as string.

```js
var now = moment();
var duration = moment.duration(now.diff("2017-01-09T10:23:13.000Z"));
var hours = duration.asHours();
console.log(hours)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) specifying `'hour'` as second parameter.

Here a working example:

```js
var time = '2017-01-09T10:23:13.000Z';
console.log(moment().diff(moment(time), 'h'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `moment.duration` and `duration.asHours` methods.

```
var startTime=new moment(`2017-01-09T10:23:13.000Z`);
var end=moment();
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.asHours();
console.log(parseInt(hours));
```

```js
  var startTime=new moment(`2017-01-09T10:23:13.000Z`);
var end=moment();
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.asHours();
console.log(parseInt(hours));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```