# How to get the difference between 2 dates in hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

i'm trying to get the difference between 2 dates in hours using `momentjs`,

but i'm unable to get `hours` `count`.

here is what i have tried,

```
var date1 = moment('2016-10-08 10:29:23');
var date2 = moment('2016-10-08 11:06:55');
var diff = date2.diff(date1);

console.log(diff);
```

**Question:i** want t get result like `1 day 4 hrs`, `4 hrs 2 min` etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Comment: var diff = Math.floor((date2 - date1)/(1000*60*60))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options based on what you want to do:

```
var date1 = moment('2016-10-08 10:29:23');
var date2 = moment('2016-10-09 11:06:55');
var diff = date2.diff(date1);

var duration = moment.duration(diff);

console.log(duration.humanize(true));
// "in a day"

console.log(`${duration.days()}d ${duration.hours()}h ${duration.minutes()}m`);
// "1d 0h 37m"

console.log(duration.asHours());
// 24.625555555555554
```