# Moment.js giving Incorrect Difference between 2 Dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am using moment.js in my React app with the following code to find the difference between 2 **unix timestamps**:

```
import Moment from 'moment';

Moment.duration( 
    Moment(this.state.saleEndTime).diff(Moment(this.state.saleStartTime))
).humanize()
```

where

- `this.state.saleStartTime` is `1511638810` (Sat, 25 Nov 2017 19:40:10 GMT)
- `this.state.saleEndTime` is `1516909110` (Thu, 25 Jan 2018 19:38:30 GMT)

However it is giving the output

```
an hour
```

This is obviously not correct, it should be 2 months. What did I do wrongly?

Using moment v2.19.2 with node v7.9.0

---

Edit: Output needs to be `humanize`'ed, and the time difference between `this.state.saleStartTime` and `this.state.saleEndTime` can range from minutes to months...

Comment: shouldn't you pass a unit to [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Comment: @Sag1v What unit should I pass if the 2 unix timestamps can be minutes or months apart, and the output should be `humanize`'ed?

Comment: @TheMintyMate Sorry for the confusion, it is not a duplicate. Edited question, Sag1v provided solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't realize it's a `unix` stamp.
You should use the [`unix`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) method then:

```
moment.duration(
  moment.unix(1516909110).diff(moment.unix(1511638810))
).humanize();
```

Running snippet:

```js
const result = moment.duration(
  moment.unix(1516909110).diff(moment.unix(1511638810))
).humanize();

const App = () => (
  <div >
    <div>{result}</div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.19.2/moment.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```