# How i get days accurately in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

This is my code for getting days difference from given dates.
I need the days accurately, Here my correct days different is '2'
but i am getting 1.
i am using moment.js for this operation in angular. This is not taking time .
I need time to take for getting result.
I am using this code in calendar so i need to take time too.

```
var startdate=new Date('2017-12-30 06:00:00');
var enddate=new Date('2018-01-01 01:00:00');

var diff=  moment(enddate).diff(startdate, "days");
console.log(diff)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Comment: Do you want to ignore the time?

Comment: @HassanImam Ino i need to add time . Consider as next day, here one hour will increase on next day here we consider as a next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Difference 1.0.0+](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)
>
> ...
>   By default, `moment#diff` will truncate the result to zero decimal places, returning an integer. **If you want a floating point number, pass `true` as the third argument**. Before 2.0.0, `moment#diff` returned a number rounded to the nearest integer, not a truncated number.

```js
var startdate = new Date('2017-12-30 06:00:00');
var enddate = new Date('2018-01-01 01:00:00');

var diff = moment(enddate).diff(startdate, "days", true);

console.log(diff);            // 1.7916666666666667
console.log(Math.ceil(diff)); // 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `startOf`, to remove time part of both dates.

```
moment(enddate).startOf('day').diff(moment(startdate).startOf('day'), 'days');
```

Comment: change this to => moment(enddate).startOf('day').diff(moment(startdate).startOf('day'), 'days');

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Yes, you have to adapt to your case. I edited the answer

Comment: Fine @Soulbe. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this vanilla JS solution

```
var numberOfDays = Math.ceil( ( enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime() ) 
                     / ( 1000*60*60*24 ));
```

**Demo**

```js
var startdate=new Date('2017-12-30 06:00:00');
var enddate=new Date('2018-01-01 01:00:00');
var numberOfDays = Math.ceil( ( enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime() ) 
                     / ( 1000*60*60*24 ));
console.log( numberOfDays );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var startdate=new Date('2017-12-30 06:00:00');
var enddate=new Date('2018-01-01 01:00:00');
console.log( moment(enddate).diff(startdate, 'days'))
console.log( moment(enddate).diff(startdate, 'weeks'))
console.log( moment(enddate).diff(startdate, 'hours')) 
console.log( moment(enddate).diff(startdate, 'minutes'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: TO is already using `.diff(..., 'days')`, but _"Here my correct days different is '2' but i am getting 1"_