# How to get the total Hours by Subtracting two dates using moment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

i have to subtract two days and need to get the total hours.

```
let date1 =  moment.tz(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", "America/Chicago").local().format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');

let date2 =  moment.tz(titleDate, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", "America/Chicago").local().format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');


let getHours = date1.diff(date2, 'hours')
```

i need to get the total hours like this way. any different way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: getting date1.diff(date2) is not a function error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Comment: `diff ()` is function of `momentjs` not of `moment-timezone` library so make sure you have added `momentjs` library as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also you can use,

```
let date1 =  moment.tz(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", "America/Chicago").local();
let date2 =  moment.tz(titleDate, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", "America/Chicago").local();
var x = moment.duration(date1.diff(date2)).asHours();
```

from [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/)

Answer (score 2):

The `format` function returns a string. So, in your code, `date1` and `date2` are strings, not momentjs datetime values. Remove the call to `format()`.

Answer (score 0):

After formatted, the date1 does not have diff method which is a string. You can remove the format.

```
let date1 =  moment.tz(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", "America/Chicago").local();
let date2 =  moment.tz(titleDate, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", "America/Chicago").local();
let getHours = date1.diff(date2, 'hours');
```

Or if date1 and date2 are in same timezone:

```
let date1 =  moment();
let date2 =  moment(titleDate);
let getHours = date1.diff(date2, 'hours');
```

Or

```
date1.diff(date2) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
```

`date1.diff(date2)` return milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var titleDate = new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30);
var originalDate1 = moment.tz(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", "America/Chicago").local();
var date1 =  originalDate1.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
var originalDate2 = moment.tz(titleDate, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", "America/Chicago").local();
var date2 =  originalDate2.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
console.log(date1+"\n"+date2);
var duration = moment.duration(originalDate2.diff(originalDate1));//myMoment.diff(now, 'days', true);
var hoursDuration = duration.asHours();
console.log(hoursDuration);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js"></script>
```