# Moment diff between two Dates

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment

im struggelting to get the right output from 2 dates.

```
var destinationTime = moment("2019-05-07T16:59:00");

moment.utc(moment(destinationTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(moment(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

And im want to get the output only in HOURS, so its only works for a dates at the same day.

if the destinationTime is in for example 7 May, its ignore the day
 getting worng output :
"03:11:22"

expected behavior return me the time between two dates by hours "216:11:22" <-- hours and minutes and seconds

Comment: A possible duplicate of your question. Please see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thanseeh/ahq52xfj/1/

```
 var destinationTime = moment("2019-05-07T16:59:00");

moment.utc(moment(destinationTime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss").diff(moment(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: you could change days to required props

Comment: it only show me the right hours 194, but i want the hours as Format with minutes and seconds "HH:mm:ss"

Comment: its not work as expected, it IGNORE the actually date.the output is "02:27:22" 2 hours 27 min, when is should be somthing like 216 hours 216:27:22, because the destination date is 7/5/2019

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192563/discussion-between-roberto-and-abdulla-thanseeh).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
let date1 = new Date(params.data.incidentTime).getTime();
let date2 = new Date(params.data.creationTime).getTime();
let time = date1 - date2;  //msec
let hoursDiff = time / (3600 * 1000);
```

Or depending on your needs a shorter version

```
var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;
```

- 36e5 = 60*60*1000