# Moment not giving me difference in days between two dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I have a code like this where I have my date and current/today date and I need to get difference in days between two dates. I always get 0 or some big number "31536000000" Whats wrong?

```
const startDate = moment(job.published_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY,MM,DD')  //looks like this "2018,08,19"
const endDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY,MM,DD') //looks like this "2019,09,12"
const a = moment([ startDate, ])   
const b = moment([ endDate, ])
console.log('DIFFERENCE IN DAYS', b.diff(a))
```

Comment: what is the exact value of `job.published_date`

Comment: it is a string that looks like this for example 2017-08-16

Comment: Does Moment *know* what format `startDate` and `endDate` are in? Because you are trying to parse them from one known format into another, then parse them into Moment objects again and this might fail on the second step.

Comment: not sure if it knows. Do I need to add something somewhere. job.published_date is a string that looks like this for example 2017-08-16 and for endDate I just get new Date and format it like the startDate

Answer (score 4):

```
const startDate = moment('2017-08-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY,MM,DD')  //looks like this "2018,08,19"
const endDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY,MM,DD') //looks like this "2019,09,12"
const a = moment([ startDate, ])   
const b = moment([ endDate, ])
console.log('DIFFERENCE IN DAYS', moment.duration(b.diff(a)).asDays());
// DIFFERENCE IN DAYS 730
```

you need to get a duration value from moment after the diff - then format it as days.

this helped

[Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Comment: `console.log('DIFFERENCE IN DAYS', b.diff(a, 'days'));` also returns 730

Comment: yea that may be better Michael

Comment: Ok. Seems something is wrong with using a variable. If I use "2017-08-16" in startDate I get correct. But if I use variable `job.published_date` I get 0. Don't know why since I checked it, date is here before function is run and it is a string.

Comment: your  `job` object is not what you think it is , you may have a race condition where your function is ran before your variable is set

Comment: I checked that. It's not. job is fetched long before this function is run. It's weird. The khodadadi solution below worked for me.

Comment: the fact that his solution works when its wrapped in 2 different functions - leads me to believe that you are indeed running into a race condition... glad we could help you out though cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
dayCount(startDate,endDate){
  const startDateMoment = moment(startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').unix();
  const endDateMoment = moment(endDate,"YYYY-MM-DD").unix();

  const dayCount = (endDateMoment-startDateMoment)/86400;

  //or 
  //const diff = endDateMoment-startDateMoment;
  //const dayCount = moment.duration(diff,'s').asDays()

  return dayCount
}

render() {
  let dayCount= this.dayCount("2018,08,19","2019,09,12");
  console.log(dayCount)
}
```

Comment: your solution worked for me but not sure why the one at the top didn't. Instead of using string at the date at the startdate I used variable. When I use variable that contains string value it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation it looks like you want `b.diff(a, 'days')`. Without days it's printing the difference in milliseconds
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/