# Moment.js - How do I get 1day 2hrs 30mins as hours and minutes only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to build a calculator for the worked hours during the week. 
I found a way of getting a total of worked hours, but as expected **Moment.js bubbles up (for example) the 29hours and 40mins** to  **1day 5hrs 40mins**.

How do I manipulate or stop that default behavior of **Moment.js**?

Here is what I tried

```
    const calculateTotal = function (arr) {
        let hoursInTotal = moment.duration({
            minutes: 0,
            hours: 0,
        });
        // arr is the Array I am storing the total hours of each DAY
        arr.forEach(function (el) {

            // Adding every total hours of each DAY to get the total from EVERY DAY
            hoursInTotal.add(el.hours.total);
        })
        // I am getting 35.25hrs, for example. I want to get 35(h):15(min)
        console.log(hoursInTotal.hours());
        return hoursInTotal;
    }
```

Comment: `console.log(hoursInTotal.get('hours'))` do what you need?

Comment: @Jhecht Still exceeds if the numbers are higher than 23. If the result of hours are 28, it will simply print 4hr.

Comment: And I'm assuming you've tried the hoursInTotal.asHours()?

Comment: @Jhecht Yes, as it returns 28.25. Whenever there are minutes involved, I want to simply show 28h15mins, instead of 28.25

Comment: Why not just not use a moment duration then? Pretty simple math involved to keep those two numbers as variables

Comment: @Jhecht It is already a duration. It just bubbles up the hours to days by default. And I am looking for a solution to fix that default bubbling.

Comment: Perhaps my words could have been clearer: just don't use a moment duration if this is an issue. It's not complicated to keep track of the total hours / minutes.

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150793/756514 ?