# Calculate time differences in nodejs from a manually created format

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I wanted to calculate the time differences (in minutes). However the data I gotten is not using a conventional time format, it is using the following format "yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM-ss" in UTC time. I can't use this directly in moments or other library as seems. What is the recommendations to handle this specific format?

How can I use library such as "moment" to calculate the time differences with this time format from my data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Comment: I have a problem that the data I have gotten is a manual format. This format is not a conventional format. The format is "yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM-ss"

Comment: can you share sample date here?

Comment: Sure, below is the date "2020-02-22-05-58-57"

Comment: alright, I have added answer and here is the node-cheat link: https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/day/duration.js#L9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but possibly try it with [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/), something like:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const yourSpecialFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss';
const someDateInYourFormat = '2020-02-22-05-58-57';

let now = moment(moment().format(yourSpecialFormat), yourSpecialFormat);
let then = moment(someDateInYourFormat, yourSpecialFormat);

console.log('Hours   ----> ', moment.duration(now.diff(then)).asHours());
console.log('Minutes ----> ', moment.duration(now.diff(then)).asMinutes ());
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it and it is working! I am accepting this answer so others can try the same for any special format that they are using internally in their database.

Comment: glad that it was useful for you!