# Moment js comparing difference in minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a question about Moment js.
I have a chat window and need to compare **currentMessage.dateCreated** and **previousMessage.dateCreated**. And if the difference between them is **more then 15 minutes**, I need to add a Flag/Label -> if(minutes > 15){ flag = true}).

How am I supposed to do compare minutes in chat messages with different values for dateCreated(not hardcoded)?
Thank you for your answers!!!

```
let currentMessage = moment
          .utc(conversationMessages[this.index].createdDate)
          .local()
          .format("D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"); // returns "8/10/2020 14:08:28"

let previousMessage = moment
          .utc(conversationMessages[this.index - 1].createdDate)
          .local()
          .format("D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"); // returns "8/10/2020 13:06:31"
```

Comment: Don't format them, do the comparison with the moment instances

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150793/14392422) from GregL.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody is looking for a solution to achieve the same without using Momentjs (which is now [officially in legacy mode](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)):

```js
// Set two date objects 30 minutes apart
const [currentMessage,previousMessage] = [new Date(), new Date()]
previousMessage.setMinutes(previousMessage.getMinutes() - 30 )

// Get difference by subtracting milliseconds and converting to minutes
const diffInMinutes = (currentMessage.getTime()- previousMessage.getTime())/60000

console.log('difference is:',diffInMinutes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say something like this:

```
var currentMessage = moment(new Date()); //todays time
var previousMessage = moment("2018-12-1"); // another time
var duration = moment.duration(currentMessage.diff(previousMessage));
var days = duration.asDays(); // you can choose days, minutes or whatever you need
```

Note that you dont format them before subtraction, after that you can just use your logic for flag or you can just use as a function to flag your labels. I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) or [substract](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/substract/)

```js
let currentMessage = moment
          .utc(conversationMessages[this.index].createdDate)


let previousMessage = moment
          .utc(conversationMessages[this.index - 1].createdDate)

if( currentMessage > previousMessage.add(15, 'minutes') ) {
    // do your thing
}
```