# sum hours and show total above 24 with momentjs

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I have to sum some hours and show total above 24hours.

**example:**

```
const result = moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');

result.add(moment.duration('10:00:00'))
result.add(moment.duration('10:00:00'))
result.add(moment.duration('06:00:00'))

console.log(result.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

the output is **02:00:00** and i want it to be **26:00:00**.

Comment: I suggest you to migrate from `momentjs`, [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) why

Comment: Then why not just sum up the time by separating it into hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a duration as a result, not a date. So use a duration instead:

```js
const result = moment.duration();

result.add(moment.duration('10:00:00'))
result.add(moment.duration('10:00:00'))
result.add(moment.duration('06:00:00'))

console.log(result.asHours());
// print 26

console.log(`${result.asHours()}:${result.minutes}:${result.seconds}`);
// print 26:00:00
```

Comment: this works but i wanted formatted as "HH:mm:ss"

Comment: I think just flag it as duplicate as I did instead of answering very similar answer...

Comment: I don't think it's all that similar to the one you are referring to. He is clearly asking about adding up durations here, not calculating a duration from two dates.

Comment: L.Text: that's easy based on what I posted, but sure I've added that to the answer.

Comment: There is a third party plugin related to the duration formatting: [moment-duration-format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/)