# How to create a function to calculate/sum hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I would like to create a function to calculate/sum the time.
For Example I work 40 hours per week and I want to sum all hours and minutes of each Day which I worked to find out how many hours did I work.
I tried with Moment.js but no luck :/

```js
var fTime = document.querySelector('input[id="fromTime"]').value;
var tTime = document.querySelector('input[id="toTime"]').value;
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var sum = document.querySelector(".sum");
var reset = document.querySelector(".reset");
btn.onclick = sumTimes;


function sumTimes(){
  sum.innerHTML = "You Worked " + tTime + " hours";
  reset.style.opacity = 1;
}

reset.onclick = (e)=>sum.innerHTML = "00:00"
```

```css
div.hours{
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  heigth:70px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}
.hours > *{
  margin:3px;
}
.reset{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hours">
    <h2>Your Time</h2>
    <label for="fromTime">From: </label>
    <input id="fromTime" type="time" name="fromTime" value="13:30">
    <label for="toTime">To: </label>
    <input id="toTime" type="time" name="toTime" value="14:30">
    <button class="btn">Enter</button>
    <div class="sum">00:00</div>
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post and title to ask something more specific. Don't make us analyze your entire app to see what does and doesn't work.

Comment: Currently you're just dumping the value of your second input into the time worked text. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: I know it dosn't work, but I tried with moment.js and I didnt know what to do, this is y I just wrote it down :/

Comment: You need to show your attempt, not just ask for a solution.

Comment: So are all your volunteer helpers.

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate the `totalMinutes` worked by splitting the from time and to time into their hour and minute components.

Once we have the total minutes worked, we can format this as hours and minutes using a `minutesToHoursAndMinutes()` function.

If we enter a To: time that is earlier than the From: time, we'll show an error rather than trying to show a negative time.

I've added a `getTotalMinutesWorked()` function that will calculate the total minutes worked from the user inputs.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var sum = document.querySelector(".sum");
var reset = document.querySelector(".reset");
btn.onclick = sumTimes;

function getTotalMinutesWorked() {
  const fromTime = document.getElementById('fromTime').value;
  const toTime = document.getElementById('toTime').value;

  const [fromHours, fromMinutes] = fromTime.split(':');
  const [toHours, toMinutes] = toTime.split(':');
 
  // Total minutes worked is calculated by getting the difference in hours x 60 and adding the difference in minutes.
  return (toHours - fromHours) * 60 + (toMinutes - fromMinutes);
}

function sumTimes() {
  const totalMinutes = getTotalMinutesWorked();
  if (totalMinutes < 0) {
      sum.innerHTML = "The To time should be later than From time"
      return;
  }

  sum.innerHTML = "You Worked " + minutesToHoursAndMinutes(totalMinutes)  + " hours";
  reset.style.opacity = 1;
}

function minutesToHoursAndMinutes(minutes) {
    const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    const mins = (minutes % 60);
    return (hours + '').padStart(2, '0') + ':' + (mins + '').padStart(2, '0')
}

reset.onclick = (e)=>sum.innerHTML = "00:00"
```

```css
div.hours{
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  heigth:70px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}
.hours > *{
  margin:3px;
}
.reset{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hours">
<h2>Your Time</h2>
<label for="fromTime">From: </label>
<input id="fromTime" type="time" name="fromTime" value="13:30">
<label for="toTime">To: </label>
<input id="toTime" type="time" name="toTime" value="14:30">
<button class="btn">Enter</button>
<div class="sum">00:00</div>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, how to add the time to a variable, so every time I click on "Enter" button, the variabl sums the result time?

Comment: Do you wish to store the total minutes worked?

Comment: it would be awesome (plus explanation) :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using moment.js

look the following article:

[use moment js for difference two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

or pure javascript code

//sumTimes();

```
function sumTimes(){
 var day1 = Date.parse('01/01/1900 14:00');
 var day2 = Date.parse('01/01/1900 19:00');
 var diff = Math.abs(day2 - day1);
 console.log(diff);
}
```

this will give difference by miliseconds.

Comment: 1. OP already said `I tried with Moment.js but no luck :/` so suggesting "you can use moment.js" isn't very helpful without more info. 2. please don't ONLY link to external pages, as those pages may disappear at some point and then your answer becomes useless. Please edit your question to include a complete explanation of how to use moment.js to do this.

Comment: Please see [answer] for more tips.

Comment: Thank you @tayfun, I merged it with another code and got what I need. :)

Comment: @HamidD glad i could help