# How to calculate exact time differance b/w two dates using moment in react native

Tags: react-native, momentjs

when date is come is 3 days ago or not today how to calculate time difference b/w them. I want result in hh:mm:ss using moment in react native.

Final result like this:
example if the clockin is 3 days ago from today then time will be 72:56:59 something like this.

I try to use this

var ax = moment(
new Date().toLocaleString(),
"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
).diff(
moment(
"27/02/2023 07:16:55",
"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
)
);

But not working.. Pls help. I try to solved last two days

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js).
You'd need to use `asHours`

```js
var hours = duration.asHours();
```

You can do your own logic, or use libraries like momentJs or dateFns. I personally do not like using momentJs, since it is a big library.

Comment: let trackStartTime = props.actualTimeIn;
 let trackEndTime = curruntTime || moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
 let overallActivity = moment.duration(
 moment(trackEndTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(
 moment(trackStartTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
 )
 );

Comment: let hours = overallActivity.asHours();
 hours = hours.toString().split(".")[0];
 let miniutes = overallActivity.asMinutes();
 miniutes = miniutes.toString().slice(0, 2);
 let seconds = overallActivity.asSeconds();   seconds = seconds. toString().slice(0, 2);

 const time = hours + ":" + miniutes + ":" + seconds;
 console.log("TIME IS", time);

 currentTime = time;
 setCurrentTime(time);

Comment: Using above I got my exact difference the problem is I want to show my seconds in two digits so , seconds = seconds. toString().slice(0, 2);  when I add this my timer not start automatically and when I not slice it timer work properly, but I want display seconds in two digits and timer also start... How to fix it pls help I am stuck last two days